# ORMLite data backup and restore on Schema Change

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite, sqliteopenhelper

Im using ORMLite as the data persistence option in my android application. I want to ensure data backup and recovery on re-install. If i make some changes in the app logic and re-install the application the data is unchanged, but how can i handle the schema change, i the new version of app has some database schema changes how can i handle the import of user data into newer schema. Please guide me towards possible solutions i can avail.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how can i handle the schema change, i the new version of app has some database schema changes how can i handle the import of user data into newer schema

If I'm understanding the question, it's not about import but it is about schema updating when you install a new version of the OS.  ORMLite actually has a section about that:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/upgrade-schema

To quote, you need to override the `onUpgrade(...)` method and do something like:

```
abstract void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database,
      ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
      // we added the age column in version 2
      dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN age INTEGER;");
    }
    if (oldVersion < 3) {
      // we added the weight column in version 3
      dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN weight INTEGER;");
    }
}
```

If I'm not getting your question then please edit your post and I'll add more information.

Comment: tnx @Gray i was kind of hoping that you shall answer the question, i was thinking of detecting automatic schema change but then i came to know that with each schema change i have to manually handle it... tnx for your help

Comment: just one thing how can the values of `oldVersion` and `newVersion` are maintained, internally or i have to manage them manually?